# unknown syntax in my code for java

Tags: java

I am getting syntax error for `index.hasNext` and `input.nextInt();` right before the end of my while loop. The "input.nextInt();" for "weights[index] = input.nextInt();" works but not for "types[index]".

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Horse {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input =null;
    int[] weights = new int[100];
    String[] types = new String[100];

    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File("horseData.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(" Error FIle Not FOund");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }//end catch

    int index = 0;
    while (index.hasNext())     {
        weights[index] = input.nextInt();
        types[index] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" Weight: "+ weights[index] + ", types:" + types[index]);
    }//end while

    input.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < types.length;i++)
        System.out.println((i+1) + "\t" + amountOfFeed(types[i], weights[i]));

}//end main

public static double amountOfFeed(String horseType, int horseWeight)    {
    if(horseType.equals(" maintance") || horseType.equals(" light work") )
        return horseWeight * .02;
    else if (horseType.equals(" Moderate work"))    
        return horseWeight * .025;

    return horseWeight * .03;

}


}
```

Thank you:)

Comment: `index` is an int primitive. It has no `hasNext()` method.

Comment: to expand on what @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas said, primitives in general don't have any methods

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
int index = 0;
while (index.hasNext())     {
```

You declared `index` to be a primitive type int. Primitive types aren't objects, you can **not** call methods on them!

So, what you probably meant was:

```
while (input.hasNext()) ...
```

Thing is: details matter. Therefore it is helpful for example to avoid using names that are **too** "close" to each other (so that you accidentally use `index` when you actually meant `input`).

Answer (score 2):

Change the following

```
while (index.hasNext())
```

To

```
while (input.hasNext())
```

You may also need to increment the `index` inside the while loop using `index++`

Answer (score 0):

Primitive Data types needs to be converted to Objects before we can call them using methods()

Comment: True, on the one hand, but not really helping in this case.